# How to add FileList array into <input type='file' > control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, file, filelist

In this scenario, I have two file type input control.

> **Html:**

```
<input type="file" id="file1" multiple="multiple" />
<input type="file" id="file2" multiple="multiple" />
<input id="btn1" type="button" />
```

> **Script:**

```
<script>
var fileList = [];
$('#file1').change(function (e) {
   var files = e.target.files;
            $.each(files, function (k, v) {
                fileList.push(files[k]);
            });
});
$('#btn1').click(function(){
  //Stuffs to be added for pushing the array of File object from "fileList" array to "file2"
  //How to achieve it or is that impossible to do it?
});
</script>
```

I want to achieve the below steps:

step 1: On ***"file1"*** input change, it will push the files into the array.

step 2: On ***"btn1"*** button click, I need to set or push the array of File objects into the ***"file2"*** input control. But I can't do it and I have googled for it. I didn't find a solution for it.

I can't achieve the step 2 and help me on it.

Also provide some links which may be helpful for me.

Comment: Change the html to <input type="file[]" id="file1" multiple="multiple" />

Comment: @amit When I changed file to file[], it's warning me that, 'The values permitted for this attribute do not include []'.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is use DataTransfer Object.

```
// first create a var DataTransfer
/*
Used to hold the data that is being dragged
during a drag and drop operation. 
It may hold one or more data items,
each of one or more data types. 
For more information about drag and drop, 
see HTML Drag and Drop API.
*/
let data = new DataTransfer();

// now you need to iterate this
let el = document.getElementById("#myInput");
 for (let c = 0; c < el.files.length; c++) {
        // @ts-ignore
        let file = el.files[c];
        data.items.add(file);
      }

// then you can put the data files to any input file you want
let el2 =  document.getElementById("#myInput2");
el2.files = data.files;
```

Extra: If you wanna slice file data you need to use a for loop, array's slice method doesn't work with it.

```
// this snippet slices a data transfer alike data.slice(0,4)

let t = data.items.length;
for (let c = 0; c < t; c++) {
        c >= 4 && data.items.remove(c);
      }
```

Best Regards